# Customise scrolling behaviour of LazyColumn in Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, lazycolumn

How can we scroll one item at a time with each scroll in LazyColumn?

I have achieved this functionality by using VerticalPager.

Comment: How about using the `nestedScroll` in your `LazyColumn` this will allow you to receive nested scroll events

Comment: Can you give an example code?